# DB2 XML framing depends upon field name

Tags: db2, db2-400

My table contains below fields:

- `Pos_name` means field name
- `Pos_value`: value of field
- `Row_numb`: row number of Pos_name
- `Row_count`: row count of Pos_name

  ```
  Pos_name    Pos_value   Row_numb   Row_Count
  child_id    10           1          1
  child_id    11           2          1
  first_name  MATHEWS      1          2
  first_name  KAINE        2          2
  ```
- `Row_numb`: it's for `rownumber` of `Pos_Name`. That means have 2 child ids, so thats why we have 1,2
- `Row_count`: `child_id` is a one field name, so it's framing 1 and for `first_name` is the second Field so its framing 2.

Expected result:

```
  <row>
        <child_id>10</child_id>
        <first_name>MATHEWS</first_name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <child_id>11</child_id>        
        <first_name>KAINE</first_name>
    </row>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question, if you need a single xml document or one document per "row", and if you need an xml data type or its serialized string representation. It would be good to specify above in the question explicitly.
The example below is for serialized form of one xml document per "row".
If you want a single document - uncomment the commented out rows.
If you want xml data type values, then comment out the rows pertaining to the `XMLSERIALIZE` function.

```
WITH T(Ele_name, Ele_Value, Row_numb, Row_Count) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('child_id', '10', 1, 1)
, ('child_id', '11', 2, 1)
, ('first_name', 'MATHEWS', 1, 2)
, ('first_name', 'KAINE', 2, 2)
)
SELECT 
XMLSERIALIZE (
--XMLELEMENT(NAME "doc", XMLAGG (
XMLPARSE
( DOCUMENT 
  '<row>'

|| COALESCE (
  '<'||A.ELE_NAME||'>'
||A.ELE_VALUE
||'</'||A.ELE_NAME||'>'
, '')

|| COALESCE (
  '<'||B.ELE_NAME||'>'
||B.ELE_VALUE
||'</'||B.ELE_NAME||'>'
, '')

||'</row>'
) 
--)) 
AS VARCHAR(200))
doc
FROM T A
LEFT JOIN T B ON A.ROW_NUMB = B.ROW_NUMB AND A.ELE_NAME <> B.ELE_NAME
WHERE A.ROW_COUNT=1
;
```